# JavaScript Error "Undefined is not an object"

Tags: javascript, object, adobe, undefined, adobe-indesign

I am attempting to debug javascript that runs inside Adobe indesign. The first executable line returns an "undefined is not an object"

```
if ( app.documents.length==0 ) { exit(); }
```

Could Adobe have moved the nested object "documents" to a higher level?

Comment: Either `app` or `documents` is undefined. I don't know enough about the scripting environment to say which; if you can output debugging info, try `console.log(typeof app)` to see if you have a handle on the right `app` object.

Comment: You need to include more information. whats in app, what is documents, etc. maybe JSON.stringify(app) and include that in your question

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be safe but to be effective make sure script is properly targeted.
I.e. if your debug is processing from ESTK - choose a target application from left-up corner dropdownlist or place this line in code's very top:

```
#target indesign
```

Comment: Possible targets are: aftereffects
acrobat
aftereffects
audition
ame
bridge
contribute
devicecentral
dreamweaver
exman
encore
estoolkit
fireworks
flash
illustrator
indesign
indesignserver
incopy
photoshop
premierepro
soundbooth http://estk.aenhancers.com/5%20-%20Interapplication%20Communication%20with%20Scripts/application-and-namespace-specifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

Cashmirek is probably right. If you are running your script from inside ExtendScript ToolKit, you need to either type in the #target instruction or pick InDesign in the application list.

Answer (score -1):

To be safe I would suggest, you use something like this:

```
if (app === undefined || app.documents === undefined || app.documents.length === 0) { 
    exit();
}
```

The `exit()`will be performed if `app` or `app.documents` or `app.documents.length` is undefined or `app.documents.length` is `0`. It eliminates the exception problem, because Javascript will stop evaluating the conditions, after one found 'true'.

Be sure to use `===` instead of `==` to ensure type comparison.

Hope that helps

Comment: Better to: throw "No active project!"; instead of exit();